# jQuery image load - multiple finish function execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-load

I am loading an image and appending it into a *img* element inside the DOM with jQuery when an thumbnail is clicked. Here is the code which does that:

```
$("#holder a").click(function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $img = $("#picture-holder img");
    $img.attr("src", $this.attr("href")).load(function () {
        console.log("done..");
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The weird thing here is that when it is finished loading, it write one log as expected at the first time. But the second time, it does that twice the previous size (which is 2). The third time, it log it for 6 times.

I am not sure what is going on here. When I check how many *img* elements `#picture-holder` holds, it returns 1 after every operation.

**Edit 1:**

I changed the code as below and mentioned problem is gone but I am not sure if it is the right way:

```
$("#holder a").click(function (e) {
    var $img = $("#picture-holder img");
    var $_img = $img.clone();
    var _href = this.href;

    $_img.attr("src", _href).load(function () {
        console.log("done..");
        $img.attr("src", _href);
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**Edit 2:**

Also, I now realized that this consumes a lot of CPU on clients machine. I am doing something wrong but where?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you're adding a new `load()` handler every time the image changes.

Comment: thanks! so my implementation was wrong I guess. I edited the question. Can you have a look?

Answer (score 0):

You should NOT bind the `load()` handler inside of the `click` method. Or, you can `unbind`the `load` handler and `bind` it again. Like this: `$e.unbind('load').load(function(){})`
But be careful, `unbind` method remove ALL handlers registered with 'load'.